# Connection refused sequelize server to mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose, sequelize.js

I have a server application and a client application at the same folder level, where I also have a docker-compose.yaml file. This is my docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: "3.8"
volumes:
  my-datavolume:
services:
  mysql-db:
    image: "bitnami/mysql:latest"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=1234
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=one-time-secret
      - MYSQL_HOST=mysql-db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    volumes:
      - my-datavolume:/var/lib/mysql
  client:
    build: ./client
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - server
  server:
    build: ./server
    # build:
    #   context: ./server
    #   dockerfile: Dockerfile
    #   args:
    #     some-arg: 1
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./server:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    env_file:
      - ./server/.env
    depends_on:
      - mysql-db
```

When I run docker compose up everything is ok till the end I get an error indicating connection refused

```
parent: Error: connect ECONNECTREFUSED 192.168.160.2:3306
```

I tried to run each service on compose individually, database runned ok, client either, just the backend got that error.

In my backend I am doing the connection via sequelize like this:

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

const config = {
  host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
  port: process.env.MYSQL_PORT,
  user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
  password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD, // usually this type of information is place during the build process, but for the sake of simplicity I leave it here.
  database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
  dialect: "mysql",
};

const { host, user, password, database, dialect } = config;

const sequelize = new Sequelize(database, user, password, {
  dialect,
  host,
});

module.exports = sequelize;
```

where it get linked to the following .env file:

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASSWORD=1234
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234
MYSQL_DATABASE=one-time-secret
MYSQL_HOST=localhost
```

I know that password should not be shared, but this is for sake of testing, nothing more :)

Can anybody help me trying to figure out what is wrong?

Thank you all!

Comment: From the point of view of the backend container, `localhost` is the backend container, not the outer host.  You need to use the Compose service name `mysql-db` as the database host name.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation has additional details.

Comment: Actually I forgot to change that one, I already had that change, just forgot to update it here on the question. Sorry for that

Comment: here is the full example: https://github.com/FilipeCosta/one-time-secret-project